# Singlepage Wordpress size responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive, singlepage

My single-page box content is not as responsive as I'd like. When I try to read the following page: https://institutoschuman.org/en/the-monographies/ with my cellphone the text on the right side is cropped. Take a look to the screenshot:
[image]
 I've tried to change the CSS stylesheet but I haven't found out the solution. Could anyone help me?

Comment: what you tried to do in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 0px){
    .sidebar .content.singlepage {
        width: 90% !important;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! I've added it and now the text isn't cropped but I'd like to see the white box also on the right side. Now it visible only on the left side. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: reduce the width `100%` to `90%`

Comment: if you set the width 86% with important than you do not need to give the padding as well.